# VSFTPD: 500 OOPS: unrecognised variable in config file: local_root

Tags: debian, ftp, vsftpd

I have a problem with vsftpd configuration. My vsftpd version is 3.0.3  When I'm trying add local_root variable to serwer configuration vsftpd stops working. How to fix this problem?
My vsftpd config:

```
listen=NO


local_root = /DataDrive/camrecords/podworko



listen_ipv6=YES

anonymous_enable=NO

local_enable=YES

write_enable=YES

dirmessage_enable=YES

use_localtime=YES

xferlog_enable=YES

connect_from_port_20=YES


chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES



secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
```

Comment: From the docs: `It is important to note that it is an error to put any space between the option, = and value.`

Comment: That's working. Thanks for help.